# How can I figure out what "target" an object file/module is compiled for on Mac OS Lion (e.g. "x86_64-apple-darwin11.0")?

Tags: object, build, llvm, static-linking, osx-lion

I'm trying to compile some code for OS X Lion and I'm running into problems with linking the object files and libraries.  I get this error:

WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples: 'x86_64-apple-darwin11.0' and 'x86_64-apple-darwin10'

Is there a command line tool/command that I can run to see what the target of the object files or libraries is?  Then I can go back and debug the compiling to process to make sure everyone is targeting the same build.

Thanks! -Don

Answer (score 1):

For llvm bitcode modules you can disassemble them using llvm-dis and look at the module there:

```
[yendi:~] echristo% llvm-dis foo.bc -o - | grep "target triple"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.7.0"
```

Not complete information, but in general to get the architecture you'll want to use 'file':

For an individual .o file:

```
[yendi:~] echristo% file foo.o
foo.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
```

or if you're creating a bitcode file with -O4:

```
[yendi:~] echristo% /Volumes/Data/builds/build-llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang++ foo.cc -c -emit-llvm -o foo.bc -O4
[yendi:~] echristo% file foo.bc
foo.bc: LLVM bit-code object x86_64
```

which won't get you the full triple, but will get you file information.

My guess is that you have some old object files sitting around or are pass -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 on some files and not on others.

Comment: The problem is that some of the configuration processes that I am using on dependent projects use a wide range of build processes that are nearly inscrutable.  They are certainly using incompatible version-min flags, but it's tough figuring out where it's happening. Where can I find llvm-dis ?  It doesn't seem to be in XCode4.

Comment: You may need to download and build llvm from llvm.org to get it installed. It may be incompatible with the version from XCode4 though since the source base has moved on.

Not sure why llvm-dis isn't installed. I'll take a look at that, but try /Developer/usr/local/bin/ for llvm-dis just in case.